# DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [BF] at index 75 from specified code page to Unicode

Tags: c#, character-encoding, asp.net-core-webapi

On a .NET Core 2.1 Web API I am working on, I've a POST method receiving a JSON object with just one property, like this:

```
{
    "longURL": "http://foo.example.com/path/path/path/path/path/pfad"
}
```

And the method's header:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ShortenerOutputDto>> CreateAsync([FromBody] 
ShortenerInputDto input)
```

But I'm getting an exception if the input JSON contains some special characters, like this:

```
{
    "longURL": "http://foo.example.com/path/path/path/path/path/pfad¿"
}
```

Please, note that the last (¿) is the offending character.
The exception I'm getting is:

```
System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [BF] at index 75 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Boolean flush)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpRequestStreamReader.ReadIntoBuffer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpRequestStreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
```

The problem is that the exception is being thrown before entering the controllers method.

So, is there a way to avoid this? I'd like to send a BadRequest in case the input can't be decoded.

**UPDATE**

Based on @jdweng's answer, I added the following converter class:

```
public class HtmlEncodingConverter : JsonConverter
{
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(String);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)reader.Value);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

writer.WriteRawValue(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)value));
        }
}
```

and Registered as a JSONOptions:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions (opt => opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new HtmlEncodingConverter()));
```

But ReadJson nor WriteJson are not being hit if some special character is on the request.

So it seems that decoding or decoding happens before Core's tries to Convert the input. Really weird.

**UPDATE II**

Raw HTTP Request Message:

```
POST /create HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Length: 80
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "longURL" : "http://foo.example.com/path/path/path/path/path/pfad¿"
}
```

Comment: With http you need to encode/decode with System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)/System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string).  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng The request comes from the outside world, so I can't encode nor add nothing to its header

Comment: The request MUST be encoded/decode to remove special characters otherwise the request will fail.  It should already be encoded/decoded and if not the the app that is sending the message has an error.  Most likely it is encoded and you have decode before sending to JSON.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973032/decode-html-encoded-characters-during-json-deserialization

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. Please, see my update.

Comment: I do not think it is unicode encoding.  It should be a window encoding.  See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176196/why-is-displayed-different-in-windows-vs-linux-even-when-using-utf-8.  Where is the unicode coming from?  It isn't in posted code.

Comment: @jdweng at this point, I'm not sure if it's encoding issue or what. By the way,  this is how you can reproduce the error. * Create an Empty WebAPI Core application. Run the application and issue the following HTTP message with BURP: POST /api/Values HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/json

"¿"

Comment: Where is the unicode error message coming from?  Add charset to utf-8 like on following : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: @jdweng if I add Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 it works. But, again, I'm not in the role of the requestor so I can't warranty that the request comes always well formed. In fact, this comes from the security review, and I can't put this into production until this is somehow solved, due to risk it has if a possible attacker tries to explode this bug. Any application should validate any possible input, and try to don't throw exceptions that could expose stack traces or accidentally, some code.

Comment: I looks like the Net Library when it sees the character "¿" is is defaults to unicode.  When you specify charset = utf it is using the correct encoding.  The encoding is really a windows encoding (8 bites).  All you need to do is confirm that the encoding should be windows.  8 bit encoding uses for character 0 to 127 the same values.For 128 to 255 it will vary depending on the country and encoding.You do NOT want to allow unicode because that is the real bug you want to prevent.  Headers are used to negotiate mode of operation.Not putting utf-8 will allow unicode which is what you do not want.

Comment: Shouldn't you add charset=utf-8 to your server to prevent attacks?

Comment: @jdwengAs stated before, all happens before I can act, somewhere in .NET Core code or in Netonsoft library. It would be great if I could override somehow the converter or formatter. Tried before but without success.

Comment: @jdweng "Shouldn't you add charset=utf-8 to your server to prevent attacks?" Do you know how to add charset in IIS?

Comment: I s the server a webpage or a service?  If it is just an html file the adding it to the top of the file will work.

Comment: @jdweng ASPNET Web API

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853144/how-to-include-header-footer-sidebar-to-webpage-in-asp-net-c

Comment: @jdwengI really appreciate your comments. Again, it's not a web page. Is an API. There are no pages in API, therefore the link above doesn't apply.

Comment: It has to be a webpage using html format.  It may be buried in the API but it is still call a webpage because it is communicating using html format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I ended up adding an Exception filter like this:

```
public class DecoderFallbackExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(DecoderFallbackException))
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(ShortURLResponse.InvalidURL());
        }
}
```

...and register in startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
        {
            opt.Filters.Add(new DecoderFallbackExceptionFilter());
        });
```

Maybe it is not the solution I initially expected but works and allows me to take control of whatever action I should take for each case.

Furthermore, I can add input parameters to the method again, and re-enable the unit tests.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8676

BTW, it seems that this behavior will be enhanced in ASP.NET Core 3.0.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3959

Comment: Upvoted! For anyone who stumbles upon this:  
`at index X` : `X` refers to the position in the request body.   
`bytes [X]` : `X` is the character, in hex, that System.Text is trying to decode.